# This Code not working for me to start and stop instances of aws

Tags: .net, windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

```
AmazonEC2 ec2 = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonEC2Client();
```

//Start Your Instance

```
ec2.StartInstances(new StartInstancesRequest().WithInstanceId("i-00000000"));
```

//Stop it

```
ec2.StopInstances(new StopInstancesRequest().WithInstanceId("i-00000000"));
```

Comment: Can you provide more details, such as the error message you are receiving?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great (official) howto for using .net and starting instances: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/DeveloperGuide/run-instance.html

You can't name an instance yourself, and you need to specify much more information. Here's an example found on that page.

```
string amiID = "ami-e189c8d1";
string keyPairName = "my-sample-key";

var groups = new List<string>() { mySG.GroupId };
var launchRequest = new RunInstancesRequest()
{
    ImageId = amiID,
    InstanceType = "t1.micro",
    MinCount = 1,
    MaxCount = 1,
    KeyName = keyPairName,
    SecurityGroupIds = groups
};
```